# How do I create and use multiple independent components that depend on the same script (ie Google Maps API) in Backpack for Laravel?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am trying to make a Create form in Laravel Backpack that has two fields: an `address_google` field, and a custom field based on https://github.com/abr4xas/gmaps-input-backpack, which includes the Google Maps API to render a map. Each includes an import of the Google Maps API. I'm looking for a way to build this map component as an independent backpack component, which depends on the Google Maps API, and I don't want to include the Google Maps API once for each component. Here's what I've found:

When both fields are allowed to use their default import, an error is thrown stating "You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors"
[(image of the log here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE03v.png). On the actual page, the `address_google` field works, but the map doesn't render at all [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccxFv.png).

If I comment out the Google Maps import in the `address_google` field, the map does render, but the `address_google` field does not autocomplete [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni5W3.png).

If I comment out the Google Maps import in the map field, the `address_google` field will autocomplete, but the map will not render [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4a3.png).

Finally, if I put the Google Maps import link in `config/backpack/base.php` in the `scripts` part of the array, and remove the Google Maps import on both the `address_google` field and map field, I can get both to render properly [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAPQv.png), but then the google maps API is imported into every admin panel in the application, and I don't want the Google Maps library to be included globally like this.

How would I include the Google Maps API, so that the two includes do not conflict each other? More generally, is there a recommended technique for creating independent Backpack components that depend on the same script when they will be used together on the same screen?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. There's no *default* way to do that in Backpack, but here are two possible options:

**Option (1)** Only load the JS in your *custom field type* if `address_google` isn't loaded onpage:

```php
{{-- resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/widgets/gmaps --}}

@if ($crud->fieldTypeNotLoaded(['type' => 'address_google']))
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=XXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initGoogleAddressAutocomplete" async defer></script>
@endif
```

**Option (2)** Create [a Backpack widget](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#creating-a-custom-widget-type-1) with the script:

```php
@push('after_scripts')
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=XXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initGoogleAddressAutocomplete" async defer></script>
@endpush
```

and add that widget only on Create and Update for this entity, in your `setupCreateOperation()` and/or `setupUpdateOperation()`

```php
Widget::add([
    'type'    => 'gmaps_script',
]);
```

---

Of course, option 2 could be generalized as a `script` widget, where you pass the URL as a parameter, and maybe other attributes too.